# libmodbus cross compilation and install in Beaglebone

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, modbus

Can any one tell me how I can install and cross-compile libmodbus library(libmodbus.org) for beaglebone??

I tried to compile for my local machine having ubuntu installed in it and the library got installed properly and works fine. But I want to install for beaglebone. I have beaglebone's file system on my local machine(target Network file system)

I want to write a modbus master(client) rtu code and run on the board which i mentioned above. Please guide me for this work.

Comment: Have you looked at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? It provides libmodbus already.

Comment: i am very new to all this stuff. where i can find it?? i dont think that the buildroot has that library.

Answer (score 5):

**Manual cross-compilation**

You should configure the build system with the prefix of your toolchain (for example `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` for Sourcery CodeBench ARM 2013.05):

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
```

(if you can't find `confgure` script, execute `autogen.sh` first to create it), build the library:

```
make
```

Then copy library files to your rootfs:

```
cp src/.libs/libmodbus.* path-to-your-rootfs-usr-lib
```

**Buildroot flavor**

```
git clone git://git.busybox.net/buildroot
make beaglebone_defconfig
make menuconfig
```

And search for `libmodbus` "Target packages->Libraries->Networking", select it and build the entire rootfs:

```
make
```